# IIS 7.5 Crashes when sending big XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have a web service that returns a XML file.

The first request returns a XML file that its size is around 50MB, and any new request will be much smaller, more like 1KB or so.

My IIS is crashing when sending the big XML (only on the first request).

I am getting error 504, and in the eventviewer I can see:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.239, time stamp: 0x4e1822f4
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000001177
Faulting process id: 0x15cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd225011f055d0
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 5110375b-8e43-11e1-b097-001b217fde7f
```

I tried to google this error, but found nothing!

I thought maybe I should increase the application pool memory size or CPU usage, not sure if its the problem at all.

Do you guys have any idea on what could it be? how to solve it?

Comment: What message does IIS return as the response body? If your browser does not show it, you can find out using fiddler.

Comment: Cant see anything both in fiddler or in my browser, all I see in fiddle is: ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

Comment: Ok. Attach visual studio to the w3wp.exe and set it to break on exceptions (ctrl-shift-e). Plz post the full exception.

Comment: This error occure in the production environment, and we have no VS installed in there. our production works good for now, but it only occures on a certain request. any other options?

Comment: Please add the C# code which creates this XML, otherwise the C#, .Net-4.0 and ASP.Net-MVC tags aren't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

0xc00000fd is....stack overflow! So it sounds like you need to attach a debugger and see what's going on

Comment: I dont have VS installed on the machince where the XML comes from. how can I do it other than VS?

Comment: I think this is the cause. I suggest you slap catch(StackOverflowException) on everything and log the result.

Comment: Can it be solve by adding another RAM to the IIS application pool? or im not really getting it?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending little XML instead of big XML.

Comment: Since my XML is dynamic, its very problematic.

Comment: @IdoLazar: since your XML is dynamic, can you show us how you make the XML?

Comment: I just get the data from the database, and send it to the client. for smaller XMLs (like 30MB) it works perfect and fast! for bigger than that its crashing

Comment: As in you just retrieve XML from the database or you retrieve data from the database and turn it into XML? Either way, the code which creates the XML is the problem.